# GlimmerBlocker for Windows?

Tags: windows

Is there anything comparable to GlimmerBlocker that exists for Windows?

[GlimmberBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) is a local proxy server that takes web connections and filters out a tremendous amount of cruft on Mac OS X.  This is generally centric to ads and undesirable content, but also can modify anything that passes across the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/):

> Privoxy is a non-caching web proxy with advanced filtering
>   capabilities for enhancing privacy, modifying web page data and HTTP
>   headers, controlling access, and removing ads and other obnoxious
>   Internet junk. Privoxy has a flexible configuration and can be
>   customized to suit individual needs and tastes. It has application for
>   both stand-alone systems and multi-user networks.
>
> Privoxy is Free Software and licensed under the GNU GPLv2.

It supports Windows/Linux/Mac.

[image]

Comment: Good to see the recommendation.  I was hesitant to really trust that Privoxy would do the job as the homepage was a bit thin.  I was leaning towards it prior to posting this question and so this is a solid confirmation.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Proximodo](http://proximodo.sourceforge.net/):

- open-source customizable web filtering proxy server
- Windows/Linux

[image]